# Animate a Choropleth Map in CartoDB?

Tags: carto, animation, torque

I used Torque to animate points over time in CartoDB

I have a map of polygons and I want to animate the changing colors.

Over five years the intensity of the type of incident I'm mapping changes. I can make a slideshow that shows a visualization of each year in an individual choropleth map, but I'd love to be able to animate it in torque instead.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Torque doesn't support polygons... yet! But you can experiment with D3, I took a first stab using D3 and CartoDB to achieve something,

http://andrewxhill.github.io/cartodb-examples/intensity-time/index.html

[image: static]