# What tools exist for web-mapping line or polygon chloropleths over time?

Tags: leaflet, web-mapping, software-recommendations, timeslider

In my survey of timeslider web-mapping plugins I've mostly seen a focus on mapping different geometries over time, in particular points (e.g. `Torque.js`).

I want to create a choropleth map with 1000-2000 shapes and show the colors change over time. My concern with the tools I've seen is that, for example displaying 12 months over 1000 shapes would require loading 12,000 shapes into memory for mapping.

Is there a library that could take the shapes and then join timeseries choropleth values to them and enable a timeslider?

Comment: Don't forget that there is a [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange that should be considered whenever you are looking for a software recommendation.

Comment: Good point. Only 15 questions in `mapping` though

Comment: And another 12 in GIS: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gis

Comment: See R packages leaflet, timevis, and crosstalk

Comment: relevant: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92828/animate-a-choropleth-map-in-cartodb?rq=1